# Angularjs 1.8: extract header info from an URL or a GET request

Tags: angularjs

How to extract header info from URL GET request?

My web app is using angularjs 1.8.

It currently has an SSO link with the token exposed since an URL request is a GET request. This link is called by 3rd party app to access my web app. The 3rd party may come from a web app on a browser or mobile app.
for example: www.example.com\login.html?accessToken=testingXYZ. With this I know I can get the token via $location and extract the path parameter.

To improve the security, I thought of putting this access token value into the request header. However I unable to extract the header info from the caller request.

I need to extract the request header info from the angularjs controller for authentication.

**Here is the setup I attempted:**

I use Requestly plugin on chrome to inject the header, say *myToken*=XYZ, to every request I sent via Chrome.
Then I use console.log($http.defaults.headers) to print out any headers from the angularjs controller.

but "*myToken*" is undefined.

NOTE: I believe this is a request header, not the response header.

Please help!

Comment: You can use `localstorage` with key and then send key as `query string` like that: www.example.com\login.html?accessToken=myAccessTokenKey`

Comment: Hi, @AlirezaAhmadi, thanks for the response, this could be a viable solution for one web app to another web app. I am still checking if this is viable solution for mobile app to web browser. though I really hope for extracting header info from a web link, but actually is this even possible?